# Tkinter error local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a program that once the tick box is ticked it then the fields for the email appear but when it is un-ticked then the fields disappear when you press Update.

but I keep on getting:

```
emailLabel.destroy()

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'emailLabel' referenced before assignment
```

Any suggestions?, here is my code below:

```
#so when you tick the box, the value is 1 so this checks for that and sets a equal to 1 
#if the box isnt ticked then it checks a and if it is equal to 1 then it
#deletes the fields for the email and code.

#PLEASE HELP. Error is in this bit

def update(var1):
    global signupas
    global a
    print(a)
    checklist = var1.get()
    print(checklist)

    if checklist == 1:
        a= 1
        if a == checklist:

            # // but it's referenced here:
            global email
            emailLabel = Label(signupas, text="Email")
            emailLabel.grid(row=3, column=0)
            email = StringVar()
            emailEntry = Entry(signupas, textvariable=email)
            emailEntry.grid(row=3, column=1)
            codeLabel = Label(signupas, text="code")
            codeLabel.grid(row=4, column=0)
            code = StringVar()
            codeEntry = Entry(signupas, textvariable=email)
            codeEntry.grid(row=4, column=1)
    #its on about this bit: 
    if a == 1 and checklist == 0:
        emailLabel.destroy()
        codeLabel.destroy()
    
    signupas.mainloop()

#//this gets the information for the update as it checks for the check box
#//error isn't here but above so don't worry about signup().

def signup():
    global signupas
    signupas = tk.Toplevel()
    signupas.geometry('300x200')  
    tkWindow.title("database program")
    usernameLabel = Label(signupas, text="Username").grid(row=0, column=0)
    username = StringVar()
    usernameEntry = Entry(signupas, textvariable=username).grid(row=0, column=1)  
    passwordLabel = Label(signupas,text="Password").grid(row=1, column=0)  
    password = StringVar()
    passwordEntry = Entry(signupas, textvariable=password, show='*').grid(row=1, column=1)
    var1 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(signupas, text="2step verification", variable=var1).grid(row=2)                                                                            
    SignUp = partial(checkuser_email, username, password, var1)
    updates = partial(update, var1)
    updateButton = Button(signupas, text="Update", command=updates).grid(row=5, column=2)
    signupButton = Button(signupas, text="SignUp", command=SignUp).grid(row=5, column=1)
    signupas.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you edit your post with correct indentation?

Comment: OK 2 minutes please

Comment: would you like the whole code instead?

Comment: No, your problem is obvious.Because `emailLabel` is a local variable.

Comment: is it so; global emailLabel will do its Job?

Comment: Works Thanks for the help

Comment: One more question before you go:

Comment: Would I do the same for the Entry as in Entry.delete() ??

Comment: Documentation have a clear description, `Entry.delete()` should pass two arguments about `"index"`.If you want to clear the text in the widget, you need to use `Entry.delete(0, "end")`.

Comment: ok Thanks for the help. That is all m8

Comment: shall i add it as an asnwer then?

Comment: yes go on. Might as well mark this as fixed. Thanks